# Compile error using the Component Lab > Autocomplete feature for SVG Icons in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I got the following error when I ran my project on the browser:

Failed to compile:

```
./node_modules/@material-ui/lab/esm/internal/svg-icons/Close.js
Attempted import error: 'createSvgIcon' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/utils'.
```

I'm trying to implement the [Autocomplete component](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) (from the example in the "Multiple values" section).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import React from 'react';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

<Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            label="Multiple values"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
```

I tried to install SVG Icons by NPM:

```
npm install @material-ui/icons
```

And then importing them to my TypeScript:

```
import createSvgIcon from '@material-ui/icons/utils/createSvgIcon';
```

But I still have the error above. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Can you try to update `@material-ui/core` by running

```
npm update
```

Comment: I updated the npm and I got @material-ui/core@4.9.9 version and now I don't have the error. How did you know that was the problem?

Comment: i have updated to @material-ui/core@4.9.9 and still getting the error plz help

Answer (score 3):

As described in the Material-UI project [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v4.9.9) of the latest version (which is **v4.9.9** the time I'm writing this answer), there is a change related to `createSvgIcon`

[image]

The complete conversation of team can be found [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/20308).

**When I encountered the problem?**

When running a React project and I wanted to use the [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component from `@material-ui/lab`.

**How I solved it?**

I upgraded `@material-ui/core` package to v4.9.9 using this command:

`yarn upgrade @material-ui/core --latest`