# material-ui 'createSvgIcon' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/utils'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I have installed material-ui/lab in order to user the alert component, but whenever i import it with: `import Alert from '@material-ui/lab/Alert';` it fails to compile and throws this error:

```
./node_modules/@material-ui/lab/esm/internal/svg-icons/SuccessOutlined.js
Attempted import error: 'createSvgIcon' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/utils'.
```

So I tried to google this problem and found another question about the `material-ui/lab/AutoComplete` component ([This question exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037522/problem-to-use-component-lab-autocomplete-of-material-ui)) and the accepted answer was to update the material-ui/core to version 4.9.9, and it looks like it worked for the guy who asked, but sadly not for me, i have this versions of all the installed material-ui things:

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.9",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.48",
```

so now i'm asking u guys if there is another way to solve this problem, thanks

Comment: Installed exactly the same versions of dependencies (which also happen to be the latest) and everything works fine. Try removing `node_moules` and run `npm install`, so everything is up to date.

Comment: That's related to that issue for sure, as for me `"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.44"` works with `@material-ui/core": "^4.9.9"`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This issue is reported here and closed as the latest version of `/core` and `lab` fixes the issue:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20482

I had the same error and using this combination of versions fixed the problem:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10"
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.49"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: have they released /core v4.9.10? and /lab v4.0.0-alpha.49, just yesterday i was trying to update and it didn't give me that version, thanks anyways

Comment: these steps didn't work for me... still trying to figure out

Answer (score 12):

It is the @material-ui/core version problem because you don't have latest @material-ui/core version.
Remove @material-ui/core and install it again.remove node modulus and do npm install.working

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue with these versions:

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.49",
```

`npm update` didn't warn about anything but didn't resolve it either, I had to remove the `node_modules` folder alltogether and the `package-lock.json` file.  Not sure which one actually fixed it..

Also added this to the linked issue https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20482

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/lab` didn't work. But deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` then `npm install` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

try to reinstall @material-ui/lab using following command

> for npm

```
npm install "@material-ui/lab"
```

> for yarn

```
yarn add "@material-ui/lab"
```

Answer (score 1):

include this code package.json - dependencies {

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
"@mui/material": "^5.10.7",
```

}

than

import {Person} from '@mui/icons-material';

Comment: last type npm install

Answer (score 1):

It's been 3 years since the question asked and none of the answers has mentioned yarn cache.

What actually worked for me is running below code

```
yarn cache clean
```

And then reinstalling the npm (yarn) packages

To add more context, I've latest package version:

```
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.14.9",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.144",
    "@mui/material": "5.14.9",
    "@mui/types": "^7.2.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use yarn, `yarn upgrade` solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved with `yarn upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when importing icons from the now-retired @material-ui/icons library. The solution was to change the import to the new @mui/icons-material library.

https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/#update-mui-packages